# Como obtengo una ruta de un archivo subido por el cliente?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs

estoy haciendo un proyecto con ReactJS el cual se va ejecutar de manera local, mi problema, necesito obtener la ruta local de un archivo subido por el cliente (que tambien es el servidor) para poder utilizarla en Javascript, tengo entendido que no se puede por temas de seguridad pero hay una alternativa? En mi codigo actual se ingresa manualmente las rutas, aqui lo dejo:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';

function Directory(){
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese aqui la ruta de emulador" className="emulator"></input>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese la ruta de ROM" className="rom"></input>
      <input type="button" value="Añadir" className="add"></input>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Directory/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const button = document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0]
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const emulator = document.getElementsByClassName("emulator")[0].value
  const rom = document.getElementsByClassName("rom")[0].value
  const game = document.createElement("a");
  game.href = 'emufront://"" ' + '"'+ emulator + '"' + " " + '"' + rom + '"'
  game.textContent = "ingrese"
  document.body.appendChild(game)
  console.log(game.href)
})
```

Comment: si hubiera una forma, entonces ya no seria un problema de seguridad, porque ya lo habrian violado no? para que necesitas la ruta original, si el archivo va a ser "subido" a tu servidor

Comment: Me refiero a que no tengo un servidor, el programa va ser ejecutado de manera local para el usuario, el cual va especificar unas rutas locales, para ser utilizadas por el programa, busco una manera de que se pueda seleccionar rapidamente una ruta sin escribirla manualmente y poder ser utilizada en javascript

Comment: Justamente una app web no es para eso.. para el navegador, la ruta no existe.. existe un archivo que envia... desde donde lo manda... es irrelevante.. tal vez lo que vos necesitas no sea una app web... y por lo que estas contando, es muy probable....